# How to invoke method with generics args in reflect way in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to build a dynamic method invoker in Java7.

I can use following code to realize it.

```
 Method method = klazz.getMethod(methodName, argsType);
 method.invoke(klazz.getConstructors()[0].newInstance(), args);
```

However, argsType only supports Class[] type, which means generics cannot work well here. Is there any other reflect methods to make this come true?

Thank you.

Comment: "However, argsType only supports Class[] type" Yes, and you are supposed to pass a bunch of `Class`es. So what, exactly, are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

for args you could try new Object[}{} notation, i can't try it right now but using an object array you could pass all of your parameters.

Comment: You mean that just using array to replace list?

Comment: yes you can pass an object array for method parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Generic information is erased by the compiler. It means that during run time, all Generic types are considered to be `Object` (for instance, all `List<String>` become `List<Object>`) so what you're asking is impossible.

The way they circumvent this in the Java std lib is to supply a Class arg that can specify type during run time.  For instance, [Collections.checkedList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList(java.util.List,%20java.lang.Class)) receives a Class arg that specifies the Generic type of the list to be created

Comment: Actually if I can build a Type object by string description, it can work. But it seems no way to do this.

Comment: what do you mean "it can work. But it seems no way to do this" do you mean by calling `Class.forName()` ? what can work and what has no way??